# How to create a CRUD for multi-level child Model with ASP.Core & EF?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a CRUD that can edit a model and all its children, but each time the parent model ends up empty, **how to properly do a scaffolded CRUD with ASP.Core 2.2**?

```
//Models

class Book {
    int IdBook {get; set;}
    string Name {getl set;}
    ICollection<Page> PageList {get; set;}
}

class Page {
    int IdPage {get; set;}
    string Name {get; set;}
    ICollection<Line> LineList {get; set;}
}

class Line{
     int IdLine {get;set;}
     string Content {get; set;} 
}
```

Here's my controller

```
//Controller

public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    var book = _context.Book
                    .Include(b => b.PageList)
                    .ThenInclude(p => p.LineList)
                    .First();

    return View(book);
}
```

Here's what I'm trying to do

```
@model Book

@Model.Name
@for(var indexPage = 0; indexPage < Model.PageList.Count; indexPage++)
{
    @Model.PageList[indexPage].Name
    @for(var indexLine = 0; indexLine < Model.PageList[indexPage].LineList.Count)
    {
        Html.EditorFor(x => x.PageList[indexPage].LineList[indexLine].Content)
    }
}
```

But when I post my form, I only get the properties of `Book`, and `Book.PageList` is `null`, what is the proper way do that? Is there any tutorial I would have missed?

UPDATE

The problem seems to be the type, the controller receives the post parameter
(My code is a bit different, but the same, the books were an example)

[image: bug]

Comment: How is book being created in ctrl?  Chances are it's not loading all properties.

Comment: Just updated the question

Comment: The view load properly, it's only on form post that children are getting null

Comment: I feel like the lazy load is working when I generate my View, but when I post to saveChanges, the lazy load is somehow disabled and the children properties are getting null, could this be a possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post entire code for the action method on the controller that processes your request?

From your code on the razor view page, in the inner loop where you are iterating through PageList, your are not incrementing your `indexLine`. Shouldn't this line

`@for(var indexLine = 0; indexLine < Model.PageList[indexPage].LineList.Count)`
be

`@for(var indexLine = 0; indexLine < Model.PageList[indexPage].LineList.Count, indexLine++)`?

Again, On the controller, if the Request.Form property has the entire 'supposed' payload but model binding isn't working, try annotating the `Submission` parameter with `[FromBody]` Annotation to clearly inform ASP.NET to bind `Submission` from bofy of the request - like so

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [FromBody] Submission submission) {}
```

Look through these tiny fixes and let me know if you still have any issues

Comment: For the razor problem, it's my bad, the mistake was only in the book's example, not in my actual code. For the binding problem, I had to make a few changes, but with ```[FromForm]``` tag, I was able to retrieve the content, thanks, I did not know this trick!